# How to check approvals for bunch of addresses

Tags: erc-20-approve

I have a list of ethereum addresses and I need to check which contracts and which approvals for a particular token they gave. I only need query approvals for one specific token. is there some efficient fast way to do this when you need to check a bunch of addresses? I tried via etherscan api but there is no such combination of filters as I need (token plus owner but without spender), same with alchemy and moralis